# How to query by passing dynamic key value pair in find() method of mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to send dynamic query to the mongoose **find()** method. For each iteration I need to send dynamic key and value in find method. Can someone help in this and I have tried below.
The query for each iteration needs to be `find({ idle_screen : value}), find({verify_address : value})`

````
const relatedDoc: any = {
          idle_screen:1, 
          verify_address: 2, 
          update_address :3
       };
       Object.entries(relatedDoc).forEach(async ([key, value]) => {  
        // Here i want to add key as property in object
        const query = { key : value} // actual o/p = {key : 1} , expected o/p = {idle_screen : 1} , {verify_address : 2} 
        var appointmentRefDocs = await appointment.find(query);
      
       })```

 Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: what problem do you face in your current code ? ,  add , `console.log('query=', query)`. `console.log('appointmentRefDocs', appointmentRefDocs)`; to check result .

Comment: in  the const query object  key value is not updating with idle_screen, verify_address , it is always going as key . I want query as {idle_screen : value} or {verify_address: value} on each iteration

Comment: updated the question with comments

Answer (score 2):

use for of loop for async operation .

```
const relatedDoc: any = {
      idle_screen:data.idle_screen, 
      verify_address: data.verify_address, 
      update_address :data.update_address
   };


 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(relatedDoc)) {
  const query = {[key] : value}
  var appointmentRefDocs = await appointment.find(query);
 }
```

Comment: Here await  will not be work without async

Comment: async should be used in outer function i.e enclosed function that have this code execution.

Comment: const functionName=async ()=>{                                                                            
 const relatedDoc: any = {
      idle_screen:data.idle_screen, 
      verify_address: data.verify_address, 
      update_address :data.update_address
   };


 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(relatedDoc)) {
  const query = {[key] : value}
  var appointmentRefDocs = await appointment.find(query);
 }

Comment: Thanks saurabh and Ethan . I have updated the answer based on your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated answer :

```
const relatedDoc: any = {
          idle_screen:1, 
          verify_address: 2, 
          update_address :3
       };
       Object.entries(relatedDoc).forEach(async ([key, value]) => {  
        
        const query = { [key] : value};
        var appointmentRefDocs = await appointment.find(query);
      
       })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const dynamicFindQuery = async (data: any) => {
        const relatedDoc: any = {
            idle_screen: data.idle_screen,
            verify_address: data.verify_address,
            update_address: data.update_address
        };
    
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(relatedDoc)) {
            const query = { [key]: value }
            const appointmentRefDocs = await appointment.find(query);
        }
    }
```

If you use Typescript, then you can use **Record<string, any>** instead of **any** as the function parameter's type.